# sql current month query

Tags: php, mysql

I'd like to show records of the current month May 2014,
I'm trying to pull a record with the following query

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE DateTime > (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

tried the query on display records using php and query it on mysql (phpmyadmin) but yields wrong records because it shows the last month's record, which is april

Maybe the query is wrong, any ideas? suggestions?

Comment: How you are saving the date..As timestamp??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the current date is May 7, then subtracting 1 month is April 7, and your query returns all rows since then. You need to start from the first date of the current month.

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE DateTime >= DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-01 00:00:00');
```

Comment: thank you! I tried all the queries here and almost all are showing correct, though this query didn't win by speed but it has the least function used, I think I should look also on performance of queries from now on

Answer (score 0):

You can do so, by using [*LAST_DAY*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_last-day)

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 
WHERE 
`DateTime` > LAST_DAY(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) 
AND `DateTime` <= LAST_DAY(NOW())
```

> LAST_DAY() Takes a date or datetime value and returns the corresponding value for
>   the last day of the month

As for the case barmar highlighted you can do so

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 
WHERE 
`DateTime` > CONCAT(LAST_DAY(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH),' 23:59:59') 
AND `DateTime` <= LAST_DAY(NOW())
```

Comment: This will return rows from the last few hours of the previous month.

Answer (score 0):

I like to write it this way:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE DateTime >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL DAY(CURDATE())-1 DAY
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the current calendar month (so all records where `DateTime` month is same as current month), you can use the `MONTH` function and `YEAR`function to extract those values:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 
WHERE MONTH(DateTime) = MONTH(NOW()) AND YEAR(DateTime) = YEAR(NOW())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
set @YM=concat(year(now()),'-',month(now()));

select
    *
from
    table1
where
    concat(year(DateTime),'-',month(DateTime))=@YM;
```

It's not elegant but it'll work